# How to Redirect to Another Page in PHP based on drop down selected value/text?

Tags: php, html, sql, drop-down-menu

My code now works. Thanks everyone! Here is the final code in case anyone else ends up having the same trouble as I did.

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');
$query = "SELECT * FROM classroom";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<?php
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['classname'];?>"> <?php echo $line['classname'];?> </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'select1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( "url/viewclass.php?classname="  + this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I am not. I haven't learned about jquery yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your html the value attribute of the MATH option is empty, fill it like your php code above.

you should place  `viewclass.php?classname=` in `open` method and concatenate it with selected item.

HTML:

```
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
<option value="MATH 2072">MATH 2072</option> <!-- php script should fill value -->
<option value="SCIENCE 1072">SCIENCE 1072</option> <!-- php script should fill value -->
</select>
```

JS:

```
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( 'viewclass.php?classname=' + this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
```

[Here's a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbs88j78/)

Comment: i left it empty as an example of what I used before. If I add a class to my database I want my drop down list to update automatically with going into the code and adding it myself. I am wanting to populate the drop down menu from my database with a while loop. Once the drop down menu is populated I want the name of any of the classes that appear to redirect me to the viewclass.php of that class.

Comment: I understand the JS part now. Sorry I am still new when it comes to coding. Now is there a way I could populate the drop down menu from my database and still use the js code to redirect the drop down menu?

Comment: Yes, the php code you've post was correct. The populating task is using the php code and the while loop. Once the page is loaded the combo is populated and then the js will become to use for the redirection.

Comment: It makes sense now! I do have one last question. Is there a way I can add a value to each id from the while loop? For example math 2072 needs to have the value math_2072 and history 3500 needs to have a value of history_3500.

Comment: You should store it in your database and the fetch that column in your while loop. For example for option value tag echo '$line["classvalue"]' and for combo title echo '$line["classname"]'

Comment: I understand all of it now. Thank you very much. You have helped me out a lot today.

Comment: You're welcome. We are here to help you. If you find the answer please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call function on `onchange` of select:-

```
<select name="menu1" id="menu1" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="">MATH 2072</option>
</select>
```

Create function :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
 };
}
</script>
```