# How to change the section content when drop down is selected

Tags: php, html, css

I have a page called About and that page contains dropdown of management, Trustee, and principal. When the dropdown of a particular school branch has selected the management and trustee remains the same but the principal of the particular branch should appear. How can I achieve this task with `PHP` because the complete site was built on `PHP`

Any help is highly appreciated

I am a newbie to this

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: What have you tried until now. Show us

Comment: please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pure php solution for this. You can use javascript instead.

```
    <select name="" id="select" onchange="my_function()">
        <option value="null">Please select an option ...</option>
        <option value="trustee">Trustee</option>
        <option value="management">Management</option>
        <option value="principal">Principal</option>
    </select>

    <div id="trustee" class="div" style="display: none;">
        Trustee
    </div>

    <div id="management" class="div" style="display: none;">
        Management
    </div>

    <div id="principal" class="div" style="display: none;">
        Principal
    </div>


    <script>
        function my_function(){
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div");

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(el) {
                el.style.display='none';
            });

            var e=document.getElementById('select')
            var select=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            if(select!=null){
                document.getElementById(select).style.display='block';
            }
        }

    </script>
```

There is another suggestion with less amount of JS. You can check link below:
[how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-php-based-on-drop-down-selected-value-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873478/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-php-based-on-drop-down-selected-value-text)